# Stepfather: vicpatro or duonpatro?

Tags: word-difference

I was searching for the Esperanto word for *stepfather*, and I found two words, *vicpatro* and *duonpatro*. Are there any differences, in connotation or otherwise, between these two words? If they are simple synonyms, is one more common than the other? Dankon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To your list you can also add *stifpatro*, which you'll find in at least a few dictionaries, but is far less common than the other two.

According to PIV:

> Vic- la pure nominalan parencecon inter la gefiloj el unua edziĝo de unu membro de edzoparo k la gefiloj el unua edziĝo de la alia membro:
>
> Duon- de parenceco inter la infanoj de unua edziĝo k la dua edzino de ilia patro (resp. la dua edzo de ilia patrino) aŭ inter tiuj infanoj k la infanoj de tiu dua edziĝo

The take-away here is that *vic-* has to do with non-blood relationships. Duon, on the other hand, can include both blood and non-blood relationships in blended families.

**PIV doesn't seem to allow for *vicpatro*** - but for sure it's a real word in actual use. (In fact, however, *duonpatro* is more common.) **There is no difference in meaning**.

So *duonfrato* appears to be ambiguous, since it includes half-brothers and step brother. *Duonpatro* however is not ambiguous because there's only one kind of *duonpatro* -- that is, a step father by marriage.

The question at this point, given that *vicfrato* is a step brother, and *duonfrato* is either a half brother or a step brother, how do you say simply "step brother." This is why *stif-* was proposed, but it seems that the semantic space is firmly taken up by *vic-* and *duon-* and so it isn't widely used.

Comment: I use only "vicfrato" for "step brother", and reserve "duonfrato" for "half brother". This adds a lot of clarity. And for this reason, I prefer "vicpatro" over "duonpatro" for "stepfather", even though here there is no risk of misunderstanding. For me, these are words that I actively use on a daily basis, as I speak Esperanto with my children, and I have both stepsiblings and a stepmother (and a recently deceased stepfather).

Comment: Seems like a sensible solution -- and I've been meaning to comment that I'm not 100% sure I summarized the definitions correctly - I think PIV agrees with you as far as "frato" goes. Still, it seems strange that a "duonfrato" is a blood relationship while "duonpatro" is not.